# How would you place a 'required asterisk' image in front of the first letter of a label using only css?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to place a 'required asterisk' image in front of the first letter of a label only using css?  The text of the label is right aligned, so there is a varying length of space in front of the text of each label.

Comment: Look here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/ it can point you in the right direction. I suggest use of the :before element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
.foo:before {
    content : "* ";
    color   : red;
}
```

Comment: I am using an asterisk image, which also works when set for content.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE 9.  I have `label.required: before { content: '*'}`. It works in IE < 8, firefox and chrome. Any suggestion on a work around for this to work

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with some CSS, but it won't work with IE.  First, you need to create a bulleted list.

Next, hide the list-item-bullet:

```
ul > li {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
```

then add a new symbol in front of the list-item:

```
ul > li:before {
    content:"*  ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to place an *image* using CSS, without modifying content, then you need to use a background image, e.g.

```
label {
  padding-left: 12px;
  background: url(asterisk.png) no-repeat;
}
```

This implies an accessibility problem: people using nonvisual browsing won’t get the information about requiredness, since there is no way to specify a textual alternative to a background image.

On the other hand, to limit the effect to only such labels that relate to required fields, you would need to use a class selector, say `label.required`, and add a `class` attribute to the relevant `label` elements. Then I suppose you could just as well modify the content by adding an actual image before the relevant `label` elements, without resorting to CSS, e.g.

```
<img src=asterisk.png alt="Required "><label ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `padding`.

```
<label for="required"><span>Required</span></label> 
<input type="text" name="required" id="required" />
```

CSS:

```
label {
    text-align: right;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
label span {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/5x5) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/j475V/1/

Comment: To whoever downvoted, I misread and thought it said *to the right* and not *to the left*. I updated my answer.